# Getting the value of an item that is part of items with the same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the cost of some items so that I can use to calculate some data on value change of an option select. Given that the layout is dynamically generated, I have used class `charge` instead of ID  `charge`  to identify the items from which the cost is to be gotten, the option select has the class name `quantity`. The generated layout looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nzCt.png

Bellow is the generated code

```
            <td><u class="text-success"><b>Delux Single</b></u><br><small></small></td>
            <td> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
            <td colspan="3"><table><tbody><tr>
                <td class="charge"><p>1600</p></td>
                <td class="text-success">Bed Only</td>
                <td><select name="quantity" class="quantity" required=""><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></td>
                </tr><tr>
                <td class="charge"><p>1800</p></td>
                <td class="text-success">Bed and breakfast</td>
                <td><select name="quantity" class="quantity" required=""><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></td>
                </tr><tr>
                <td class="charge"><p>2000</p></td>
                <td class="text-success">Half Board</td>
                <td><select name="quantity" class="quantity" required=""><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></td>
                </tr><tr>
                <td class="charge"><p>2200</p></td>
                <td class="text-success">Full Board</td>
                <td><select name="quantity" class="quantity" required=""><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></td>
                </tr></tbody></table></td>
            <td><a href="">Reserve</a></td>
```

Now what I want is that if the quantity option is changed, its corresponding charge's value is gotten and then the calculation done.
So far I have tried the following code which is able to get the value of the changed option but does not get the charge;

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".quantity").on('change', function(){
        var value = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
        var cost = $(this).prev('.charge').text();
        alert("value",value,"cost", cost);
        });
    })
```

What could I be doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your new code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".quantity").on("change", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var cost = $(this).parent().parent().find(".charge p").text();
    console.log("value: ", value, "cost: ", cost);
  });
});
```